# Sweetness level for a dry mead

Tags: mead, sweetness

According to BJCP guide, a dry mead is a mead with FG approximately 0.995-1.010, and semi-sweet mead is 1.010-1.025.

I have a session/hydromel (with OG=1.050) mead finishing at 1.005. It is very light, but very rich on flavor, aroma and body due to the nature of the honey. It is also carbonated.

On the flavor it stars dry and effervescent, but has a long floral finish with noticeable sweetness. Let's say it starts like 1.005, but when the bubbles disappear on the tongue on the finish it feels like 1.010. In fact lack of alcohol  (6% abv) make the mead taste sweater then it is. Also, it seems that it is a totally a psychological trick, since a mind makes it feel sweeter then it is.

The question, would it be still appropriate to enter a mead into a M1A (Dry Traditional) category, and what is the actual upper acceptable sweetness limit for dry meads?

Answer (score 1):

Enter it in both. I have a buddy who will carpet-bomb several categories with the same beer if it has elements of more than one style. You'll get feedback on whether it's too sack or too dry for the style. On the other hand, you may win both. Good luck.